# How do I get radioactive ores?

Tags: starbound

> Note: This question refers to content found only in Starbound beta. **As of the 1.0 stable version of the game, there is no radioactive ore in the game anymore.** Ships are now fueled with liquid or crystaline Echirus fuel which is found on moons.

I am at the beginning of the game quest. I finished the No Place Like Home quest by finally getting Core Fragment ores to repair my thrusters. Now my thrusters are repaired and S.A.I.L suggests that I check out a "strange gate". I'm trying to get off my first planet to get to the gate but I don't know how to simply put fuel in my ship.

I know what to get but not what buttons to press. Also I don't know how to get radioactive ore. (Suggested on wiki) Where can I find radioactive ore? How?

Answer (score 3):

After the early 2015 update fuel is no longer needed for travel in a system, only for travel between systems. When you get to the gate you'll be able to move along with the quests.

Radioactive ore can be found on radioactive planets, which you will be able to get after reaching the gate and completing the outpost quests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to travel to the gate. You have to click on the gate, and then click again on the planet's gate to select it and travel. It´s an error of the game's travel system, cause if I select the gate, I don't understand why I should have to select it again in order to travel there.